# Is it possible to change vscode status bar color on startup using specific file?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

When vscode starts, status bar color has to be setup along with specific environment variable. I have `env.js` file and there is environment variable in that file.

**env.js**

```js
...
const env = 'api.test.co.kr';
...
```

In above url, `test` could be `prod` or `qa` or `local`. From this context, I wanna change status bar color per this value on startup. I searched many extensions, but couldn't find. It means that like below.

[image]

- `test` : green
- `prod` : blue
- `qa` : red
- `local` : black

**Question**

To achieve this behavior, do I have to make **vscode extension** on my own? If not, how can I setup this behaviour?

Comment: This is a pretty neat idea for what it's worth. I think a lot of people would use this for a circumstance similar if you create an extension that does this. Should share on reddit if you do!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> To achieve this behavior, do I have to make vscode extension on my own?

Yes, to *dynamically* update the statusBar conditionally, you would need to create an extension or use an existing one that offers this functionality.

Settings specifically doesn't support `if-else`-like control flow

At this time there is no native support for conditional color customizations, but for those that don't know, you can use a setting property `workbench.colorCustomizations.statusBar.background` to statically change it; which you can apply application-wide or to a specific workspace.

In your settings file:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "statusBar.background": "#ff0000"
},
```